# How to change the size of Desktop Icons in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Is it possible to change the size of icons in Windows 8? Also is it possible to adjust the horizontal and vertical spacing between Desktop Icons?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are referring to the *Desktop* icons and not the start screen tiles? Because the Desktop icons are pretty much the exact same as Windows 7. And Windows Vista.

Comment: Did you try right clicking on desktop and selecting View Large icons or small icons?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then use the scroll wheel on your mouse.

Answer (score 2):

Click on your desktop background, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + scroll.  Changing the desktop's icon size is not a global shortcut, so it doesn't work when you have an active window. That's why the Windows key makes it seem to work, as it selects the desktop just like clicking the background does. The Windows key isn't any worse of a method; it's just not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The adjustment should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Winkey</kbd> and scroll the mouse wheel. Ctrl by itself does not work on windows 8 (at least not without the Winkey here).

Answer (score 1):

I was doing a search for the solution to this for my laptop which had mega sized desktop icons for some reason. I worked out that you have to press the windows key down and while it is down press Ctrl and then with both these keys down you do what Glen said and with 2 fingers on the touchpad you move your fingers closer together to make the icons smaller (presumably the reverse will make them bigger again).

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on a free space of the desktop, select **view** menu. There are three options:

- Large Icons
- Medium Icons
- Small Icons

Answer (score 0):

For laptops, to make the desktop icons bigger you put two fingers on the touchpad and move your fingers closer together.  To make them smaller you move them away from each other. On some laptops, move them up to make the icon bigger.

Comment: Hi Welcome to SuperUser. While that will zoom the image I think the OP was asked how to change the icon size permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I have an HP laptop. Resting the index finger on the touch pad and sliding the middle (second) finger away from it makes the icons larger. To make them smaller, with the index finger resting on the touch pad, move the middle (second) finger closer to the index finger.

Frankly, a mouse is much easier and faster for PC tasks!