# How can I adjust the length at which shortcut text is truncated?

Tags: windows-8.1, desktop

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to look like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Is this a possible solution: [Change the Size of Desktop Items](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-size-desktop-items-windows-8-64621.html). If ctrl-wheel doesn't work, use [this](http://superuser.com/a/564713/8672). If all you want to change is reduce the font size, see [this](https://techdoors.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/changing-icon-and-menu-fonts-in-windows-8/).

Comment: I don't have time to test any of this but I'm going to point you here. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2805467. Adjusting the spacing between icons may provide more room for the text. Looks like there are other interesting settings there too. Tweak at your own risk though! Bad/wrong tweaks can = unusuable system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Go to Control panel

**2.** Window Color and Appearance

*2a* Under dropdown.

**3.** select Icon Spacing Horizontal.

**4.** Play with the numbers till you get what you want to show out.

Source on other ways to change it [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2805467).

Comment: this dialog is removed since Windows 8

Comment: Any idea why the spacing in the registry is negative?  is -2750 *further apart* than -480?

Comment: Never seen that it's interesting how far away is the spacing look wise?

Comment: -2750 is definitely greater than -480 in this case.  I was able to set the vertical spacing to -2750 and the horizontal to -1250 (default) and then disable aligning icons to the grid and it's basically exactly how I want it now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Devil's Advocate I had a similar kind of problem but it was solved by changing icon size make sure you change ***icon size to large*** so that it gets enough room to display file name.

Answer (score 0):

In earlier Windows versions you can use the Window Color and Appearance dialog, but this dialog is removed since Windows 8. In msfn an user coded an tool called [Advanced Appearance Settings for Windows 8](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/163836-advanced-appearance-settings-for-windows-8/) which restores the dialog. Here change the `Icon Spacing (Horizontal)` to values you like.

[image: http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/a1e6/i4cdq2c7z79e58lfg.jpg]